# memory allocation in C for pointers

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I'm trying to build a structure called PROCESS in C, this struct should contain the ID(id) and waiting time (wt) of the process.

```
typedef struct PROC{
    int id;
    int wt;
}PROCESS;

PROCESS *pt = NULL;
```

Now I want to make more then one instance of this struct like an array.
what I want to do is something like this':

```
PROCESS pt[10];
pt[0].id = 5;
pt[1].id = 7;
```

But I want to do it using dynamic memory allocation:

```
pt = calloc(2,sizeof(PROCESS));

pt[0]->id = 5;
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: If it's really [tag:c] you don't need to cast to `struct _PROCESS`.

Comment: Use `ptr[0].id = 5;`.

Comment: Should we chalk that off as a typo or is this something you didn't know about?

Comment: Another issue: Use of "reserved identifiers", do some research on that term.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi
Edited.
Thanks for your comment, but that is not what I'm asking

Comment: @RSahu
I can do that, but I have no idea of how log the array would be.It can be really long or very small

Comment: Whether you use `ptr[0]->id` or `ptr[0].id` has nothing to do with the length of the array.

Comment: @MattBelle I didn't say that it was an answer. That's why it's a comment, [this is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49078203/1983495), and a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pt` is a pointer to `PROCESS`, `pt[0]` is the first `PROCESS` object pointed to by `pt`.
The `->` operator to access members of a struct must be used with pointers only, otherwise use `.`

```
pt[0].id = 5;
```

would be correct.<sup>1</sup>

An since you say you are doing C, [you don't need to cast `malloc` or `calloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```
PROCESS *pt = calloc(2, sizeof *pt);
if(pt == NULL)
{
    // errror handling
    // do not continue
}

pt[0].id = 5;
pt[1].id = 7;
```

Also don't forget to check the return value of `calloc` and don't forget to free
the memory later with `free(pt);`.

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>Note that this would be equivalent to

```
pt->id = 5;
```

but if you want to set `id` of the second element, you would need to do

```
(pt+1)->id = 7;
```

but I think it's more readable to do

```
pt[1].id = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct process{
    int id;
    int wt;
}processes;
```

I would allocate like this->

```
int numberOfDynamicStructs=2;

processes* myProcesses= calloc(numberOfDynamicStructs,sizeof(processes));
```

Write->

```
myProcesses[0].id=1;
myProcesses[1].id=2;
```

Read->

```
printf("%d %d",myProcesses[0].id,myProcesses[1].id);
```

Free when done..

/A